# Image upload to base64 in HTML5

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm using jasny bootstrap to include image uploads in my page. See http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

My question: I want to save this image into a Javascript database like PouchDB - so I think my only option is to use Base64 (http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html - I will be using webservices to copy this image to another website, so I think it has to be base64). But how can I convert the image to base64 string format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :

```
<input type='file' id="asd" />
<img id="img" src="" />
<div id="base"></div>
```

JS :

```
function readImage(input) {
    if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
             $('#img').attr( "src", e.target.result );
             $('#base').text( e.target.result );
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
    }
}

$("#asd").change(function(){
    readImage( this );
});
```

Comment: Is that possible given that I'm uploading an image from within the browser, not using an existing image URL?

Comment: yes, you can use simple image uploader and use that path instead. All it needs is a valid image url to convert. Here is the simplified code : http://jsfiddle.net/8bcenmae/

Answer (score 0):

You may also find [blob-util](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util) to be useful. It has an `imgSrcToBlob()` method that takes an `<img>` src and converts it to an HTML5 Blob, and can also convert it to base64, binary string, ArrayBuffer, etc.